# How to put content on top of ::before

Tags: html, css

In this template: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/

The green **social network buttons are on top** of the **purple bar**.

It is a bar generated with `::before` pseudo-element in `<header>` element.

The whole content is child of `<header>` and is behind the purple bar (I've tested it by putting `<div class="content">` a yellow border), **but this social network div is ON TOP.**

I am trying to achieve the same, and I can't. The div just sits behind the bar generated with `::before`. I've looked at the CSS and there is nothing that is making that behaviour, at least I cannot find it.

I could use another approach instead the `::before`, but I think this is a good time for learning about it.

http://jsfiddle.net/otbz03un/ (Set "position: absolute" in the ::before element to see the problem)

```
<link id="font-awesome-css" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css?ver=3.2.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6 pull-right">
                        <div class="social-nets-wrapper">
                            <ul class="social">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="facebook">
                                        <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/wp-content/themes/theme51000/images/social/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="twitter">
                                        <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/wp-content/themes/theme51000/images/social/twitter.png" alt="twitter">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="pinterest">
                                        <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/wp-content/themes/theme51000/images/social/pinterest.png" alt="pinterest">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" title="google">
                                        <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/wp-content/themes/theme51000/images/social/google.png" alt="google">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <div class="logo pull-left">
                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/" class="logo_h logo_h__img">
                                <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/wp-content/themes/theme51000/images/logo.png" alt="Language School" title="YOUR KNOWLEDGE">
                            </a>
                            <p class="logo_tagline">YOUR KNOWLEDGE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span7">
                        <nav class="nav nav__primary clearfix">
                            <ul id="topnav" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
                                <li id="menu-item-1807" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-203 current_page_item">
                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1810" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children">
                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/">Our school</a>
                                    <ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="sub-menu">
                                        <li id="menu-item-1811" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/testi/">Testimonials</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-item-1812" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/archives/">Archives</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-item-1805" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/faqs/">FAQs</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1808" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children">
                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/">Programs</a>
                                    <ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="sub-menu">
                                        <li id="menu-item-1815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-2/">Programs 2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-item-1814" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/">Programs 3</a>
                                            <ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="sub-menu">
                                                <li id="menu-item-1883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-1/">Category 1</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-1882" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-2/">Category 2</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-1881" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-3/">Category 3</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-item-1813" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                            <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-4/">Programs 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1806" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/blog/">Our blog</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
                                    <a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/contacts/">Contacts</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <select class="select-menu">
                                <option value="#">Navigate to...</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/">Home
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/">Our school
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/testi/">&ndash;Testimonials
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/archives/">&ndash;Archives
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/our-school/faqs/">&ndash;FAQs
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/">Programs
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-2/">&ndash;Programs 2
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/">&ndash;Programs 3
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-1/">&ndash;&ndash;Category 1
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-2/">&ndash;&ndash;Category 2
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-3/category-3/">&ndash;&ndash;Category 3
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/portfolio/programs-4/">&ndash;Programs 4
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/blog/">Our blog
                                </option>
                                <option value="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_51000/contacts/">Contacts
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </nav>
                        <div style="position: relative; display: block;" class="pseudoStickyBlock"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700);

.header::before {
    background: #403d5a none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: auto;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.header {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.header .social-nets-wrapper ul {
    background:#a1cd51;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
}
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:top;
    list-style:none;
}
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a { display:block; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a img { display:none; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a:before {
    background:#a1cd51;
    display:inline-block;
    width:37px;
    height:36px;
    -webkit-transition:0.8s;
    -moz-transition:0.8s;
    -o-transition:0.8s;
    transition:0.8s;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:36px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size:17px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a[title="facebook"]:before { content:'\f09a'; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a[title="twitter"]:before { content:'\f099'; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a[title="pinterest"]:before { content:'\f0d2'; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a[title="google"]:before { content:'\f0d5'; }
.header .social-nets-wrapper ul li a:hover:before {
    background:#6f6f6f;
    -webkit-transition:0.4s;
    -moz-transition:0.4s;
    -o-transition:0.4s;
    transition:0.4s;
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code in your post so we can see what's happening?

Comment: @oxguy3 I've loaded it on jsfiddle

Comment: "share your code **in your post** so we can see"

Comment: Could you also post the code in your post itself? That way, if something ever happened to your jsFiddle, other people could still get help from this page.

Comment: @oxguy3 I found it out. The first `span12` inside `container > row` must be position: relative, I am trying to find why.

Comment: From what https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ says, relative positioned elements will be always on top of static (default) positioned elements. Maybe that's why